# how can I use xbuild to build release binary

Tags: c#, xbuild

When I use xbuild it always use debug as target, how do I make it use release?

For example I would expect something like

```
xbuild --release
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to so something like this:

`xbuild /p:Configuration=Release MySolution.sln`

Check out the [MSBuild reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx) for additional options - I'm not sure if xbuild is 100% in line with what MSBuild supports, but it might be helpful to you.

Comment: wow. alias xbuild-rel="xbuild /p:Configuration=Release" is what I needed